# Rewrite string in uppercase and lowercase in Python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Phyton, that's why I'm asking you for help.
Regarding strings, you can write characters uppercase using s=s.upper() and lowercase using s=s.lower().

But how can I rewrite a given string, such that the first five characters are uppercase, the next five are lowercase, and so on, and finally the string length is written with a width of 10 characters?

Comment: There's many ways of doing this. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Users on StackOverflow will help you, **after you help yourself**.  Take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour.  Do some research: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527.
Learn how to post good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

try this in python 2.7

```
from __future__ import print_function
s='stackoverflow'
for i in range(0,len(s),5):
      if (int(i%2) == 0):
            print ( s[i:i+5].lower() ,end = "")
      else:
            print (s[i:i+5].upper(),end = "")
#If you want 10 spaces before displaying lenght
print (" "*10 ,end = " ")
print (len(s))

#if you want to reserve 10digits for displaying length replace last two lines with below  line
print ("%10d" %(len(s)))
```

Comment: @FabianVit : Good to hear. If answer is helpful please update thread as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

Here's an easy way to take a string, change it's first 5 letters into uppercase and change all following letters into lowercase.  You don't have to import any libraries for this.

```
string = "abcdefghij"

string1 = string[:5]

string2 = string[5:]

stringfinal = string1.upper() + string2.lower()

print(stringfinal)
print(len(stringfinal))
```

Comment: Hi ..What if string is of 15 characters ? and where are you adding spaces that OP requested ?